# VBA: Select specific WorkSheet as Active after CSV save and close

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a macro that fills in then saves tracking numbers to a .csv file and I want to have Worksheets(1) active when I close the Workbook.  The problem I am having is that it will save and close the Workbook on Worksheets("Tracking"). I have tried to select or activate Worksheets(1) then re-save and close but I can't seem to have it work.

Here is my code for saving the .csv file and closing the workbook.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tracking")    
ws.Select

Dim sFileName As String
sFileName = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & Left(ws.name, InStr(1, ActiveWorkbook.name, ".") - 1) & ".csv"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Save Current workbook just in case latest additions not saved.
ActiveWorkbook.Save

'Now create a CSV of the active sheet.
ws.SaveAs Filename:=sFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'turn it back on
ActiveWorkbook.Close True 'Close and quit excel
Application.Quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is have excel open on a specific sheet, you can try using the built-in workbook_open.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select
End Sub
```

The changes for selecting the sheet and the range.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
ws.Select

Dim sFileName As String
sFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Left(ws.Name, InStr(1, ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & ".csv"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Save Current workbook just in case latest additions not saved.
Sheets(1).Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save

'Now create a CSV of the active sheet.
ws.SaveAs Filename:=sFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'turn it back on
ActiveWorkbook.Close True 'Close and quit excel
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am trying to evade opening the workbook again as WorkSheets(1) is just used for an import after close.

Comment: @AndrewP. I'm not sure I understand the question anymore. The question says you want to have Worksheets(1) active when reopening the workbook, but the comment says you don't want to open the workbook again. From your code it looks like you save an excel sheet to a csv file and then close the excel. When doesn't the workbook open on Worksheets(1)? Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry I used reopen which caused the confusion.  The excel sheet is used as an import after it is closed.  The problem is that it closes on Worksheets("Tracking"), so I therefore have to open it up, Worksheets("Tracking") is active, so I select Worksheets(1), and save it again.  I would like to have it close on the proper Worksheet.

Comment: @AndrewP. Ok, I think I understand. In this case Sheets("Sheet1").Select, before saveing, should be enough. If it doesn't work for some reason, you can add a range select to ensure that it's not just acting up because nothing happens after the select. I added the lines to your code, before saving, and it worked as expected in Excel 2016.
`Sheets(1).Select`
`Range("A1").Select`
`ActiveWorkbook.Save`